# How is the amount and direction of the Sun's axial tilt as observed from other planets calculated?

Tags: the-sun, celestial-mechanics, obliquity, coordinate-systems, axial-tilt

Not long ago I asked [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/55694/on-what-four-dates-dates-do-we-observe-the-minimal-maximal-and-two-days-of-zer) question; turns out that was fairly simple to figure out given the equatorial coordinates of the Sun's north pole (just convert to ecliptic coordinates, and see when the Sun is at the specific ecliptic longitudes). It also conveniently shows you exactly what the axial tilt of the Sun is as viewed from Earth (simply subtract the ecliptic latitude of the Sun's north pole from 90°, in this case 90° - 82.75° = 7.25°).

However, what if I'd like to do the same, but for a different planet (e.g. Mars)? Are there any established ecliptic coordinate systems for them that you can do a similar conversion for? If possible I'd like some way to check both what the amount of axial tilt is as well as the direction.

Bonus points for providing some means or method (like the SollongCalc utility in the accepted answer to the aforementioned question) to calculate the exact times when the north pole is facing directly toward and away from the planet, as well as the times when the equator is facing it.